# Visual Studio Как поставить автокодировку UTF-8(no BOM)?

Tags: visual-studio

Когда я пишу код в Visual Studio на русском - он отображается нормально. Но когда я открываю где-либо еще - вместо русского языка фигня какая-то

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо вручную сохранять файлы в нужной кодировке